# Python: rename duplicates based on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, rename

I have the following dataframe in python:
With different companies and different investment rounds with only undisclosed investors. Based on some other calculations, we have managed to get a "dummy" for if we have a "new" of either type A or B undisclosed investor for one of the companies. The rule being if the sum of undisclosed investors of type A or B is more than the sum in round t, then the new investor of type A or B gets a dummy.

```
Company_ID  Customer_ID  Investor_type  Round      Dummy    
    amazon  Undisclosed       A          1          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          2          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          3          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed       A          3          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          4          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          4          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          4          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          5          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          5          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          5          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed       B          5          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed       A          1          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed       B          2          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed       B          3          0   
    Apple   Undisclosed       A          3          0   
    Apple   Undisclosed       B          4          0   
    Apple   Undisclosed       B          4          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed       B          4          1
```

What we want to do is to is to change the names of the undisclosed firms to reflect this. I.e. everytime the dummy = 1, then this will reflect a new firm name, for example like this:

```
Company_ID  Customer_ID  Investor_type  Round      Dummy    
    amazon  Undisclosed_1     A          1          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed_2     B          2          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed_2     B          3          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed_1     A          3          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed_2     B          4          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed_3     B          4          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed_4     B          4          1   
    amazon  Undisclosed_2     B          5          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed_3     B          5          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed_4     B          5          0   
    amazon  Undisclosed_5     B          5          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed_6     A          1          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed_7     B          2          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed_7     B          3          0   
    Apple   Undisclosed_6     A          3          0   
    Apple   Undisclosed_7     B          4          0   
    Apple   Undisclosed_8     B          4          1   
    Apple   Undisclosed_9     B          4          1
```

The main problem is getting it to do this correctly with "jumps" back and forth, as well as when company id switches continuing from Undisclosed_5 to Undisclosed_6 once Company_ID changes to Apple. It would also work without this rule, i.e. it just starts over from Undisclosed_1.
Have tried several codes with multiple loops etc but cant get it to work, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When does the number appended to `Undisclosed` get reset?

Comment: I do not understand either what you want or how you get there. Please elaborate and include your desired output.

Comment: The desired output is in the second dataframe, where all the undisclosed have numbers after them instead (in the Customer_ID  column). When the Company_ID switches from Amazon to Apple is where the number appended to Undisclosed  resets.